# PHP lookbehind in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, regex, lookbehind

For the following string, I would like to extract the date (Monday), time (6-8pm), and Location(Location1)

```
Date1: Monday, 6-8pm, Location1
Date2: Tuesday, 1-3pm, Location2
Date3: Wednesday, 4-6pm, Location3
```

In PHP, I would do `preg_match("/(?<=Date\d:\s)(.*),\s(.*),\s(.*)/", $input_line, $output_array);` using lookbehind regex, and  I can use $output_array to display the data separtely in an array, like:

`array[0][1] = Monday, array[0][2] = 6-8pm, array[0][3] = Location1
array[1][1] = Tuesday, array[1][2] = 1-3pm, array[1][3] = Location2
array[2][1] = Wednesday, array[2][2] = 4-6pm, array[2][3] = Location3`

I was just wondering how could I achieve the same thing in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you really use a regular expression instead of simply splitting the string? That's _much_ more efficient. In any case, [JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind in its regular expressions at all](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

Comment: You don't really need lookbehind for this. You can just match the `Date\d:\s` part and skip over it in your code.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Any examples?

Comment: `/(Date\d:\s)(.*),\s(.*),\s(.*)/`

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: That first part doesn't even need to be in a group.  With `/Date\d:\s(.*),\s(.*),\s(.*)/`, the group numbers are the same as in the PHP version (which also didn't need to use a lookbehind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to do multiple matches at once with JS RegEx, but here are some non-regex solutions:

```
var input = "Date1: Monday, 6-8pm, Location1\n"
          + "Date2: Tuesday, 1-3pm, Location2\n"
          + "Date3: Wednesday, 4-6pm, Location3";

var input_lines = input.split("\n");

var output = [];

for(var iterator = 0;iterator < input_lines.length;iterator++){
    var input_line = input_lines[iterator];

    input_line = input_line.replace(/Date[0-9]+:\s/, '');

    var line_data = input_line.split(/,\s/);

    output.push(line_data);
}
```

Or, a shorter version:

```
var input = "Date1: Monday, 6-8pm, Location1\n"
          + "Date2: Tuesday, 1-3pm, Location2\n"
          + "Date3: Wednesday, 4-6pm, Location3";

output = [];

// Just a shortened version of the loop in the previous example.
input.split("\n").forEach(function(line){
    output.push(line.replace(/Date[0-9]+:\s/, '').split(/,\s/));
});
```